# Panda's SAS PROC transpose equivalent in case of only ID, multiple VARs

Tags: pandas, sas

I would like to transform the following:

| week_no | count | mean | std | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 762.0 | 774.002734 | 0.995213 | 771.0022 | 776.4584 |
| 25 | 2971.0 | 759.702417 | 4.241902 | 750.9586 | 767.6225 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

To:

| count_24 | mean_24 | std_24 | min_24 | max_24 | count_25 | mean_25 | std_25 | min_25 | max_25 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 762.0 | 774.002734 | 0.995213 | 771.0022 | 776.4584 | 2971.0 | 759.702417 | 4.241902 | 750.9586 | 767.6225 |

In my SAS days the command was like (if I remember correctly):

PROC TRANSPOSE;
VAR count mean std min max;
ID weekno;
RUN;

or a 2-step:

PROC TRANSPOSE out=step1;
VAR count mean std min max;
BY weekno;
RUN;

which generates:

| weekno | _ name _ | col1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | count | 762 |
| 24 | mean | 774.002734 |
| .. | .. | .. |

which is fed to:

PROC TRANSPOSE out=step2;
VAR col1;
ID _ name _ weekno;
RUN;

which leads to count_24 ... count_25 etc.

How can I accomplish that with pandas?